# how to configure windows 2012 SNAT?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, iptables

I want to change source IP of out packet, on the linux system is easy to done by one iptables rule
`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.1  -p udp -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.2.1`

Is there any way to implement on windows server 2012?

I had try in Routing and remote access tool, but it could not achieve my purpose.
thanks~

Comment: See NetNat of PowerShell

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked the NetNat documentation, but also can not find the way to change the IP of outing packet. Can you provide an configure example? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Haven't ever actually used the cmdlet myself so can't be sure. (And true that the doc is a bit obscure.) Take a more careful look at `Add-NetNatStaticMapping` I guess. (But most likely you'll need to create a NAT object with `New-NetNat` first).

Comment: Sorry Tom, I provided the wrong iptables rule before, and the rule have been revised. I want to change the IP of sending out packet.

Comment: Look over https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-interface-portproxy and the https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/netsh-portproxy-windows-ip-table/24b0dbb1-8a03-48f1-b4a1-e94553461212 post maybe.